# HTML string decode in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, decode

How to decode this string in python?

```
title = '&#70;&#97;&#115;&#116;&#32;&#38;&#32;&#70;&#117;&#114;&#105;&#111;&#117;&#115;&#32;&#54;'
```

to get:

```
Fast & Furious 6
```

Thank you!

Comment: That is HTML encoded not XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this code you got char symbol from ascii rappresentation.

```
title = '&#70;&#97;&#115;&#116;&#32;&#38;&#32;&#70;&#117;&#114;&#105;&#111;&#117;&#115;&#32;&#54;'
title = title[:-1]
substring=[x.strip() for x in title.split(';')]
titleFinal = ''

for ch in substring:
    newstr = ch.replace("&#", "")
    titleFinal+=chr(int(newstr))

print(titleFinal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the built-in `html` module:

```
import html
decoded_title = html.unescape(title))
```

as your string consists of *HTML-safe sequences* (numeric character references).